# magicScroll only preform animation first time down page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using MagicScroll to animated some elements as you scroll down the page. I have been searching the web and cant find an answer but is there a way to only play the animation once, so that if they scroll back up and then down again nothing happens twice?

Answer (score 1):

the ScrollScene has the option "reverse".

If you set it to true the animation will only play once. :)